# IE prompting for credentials and unable to log in after 5 minutes

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-8

I have an ASP.Net site with integrated windows authentication running on IIS8 (Server 2012). When a user first navigates to the page using IE11, it works fine. The user is authenticated with his logged on windows user (without a prompt for credentials) and can use the site. If the user is inactive for more than 5 minutes and then tries to do something, IE11 prompts for credentials, and the user can't log on, even with correct username and password. If he closes the browser window and opens a new one, everything works fine again. This only occurs in IE11 (previous versions doesn't work at all, but that's not a problem) and Edge, Chrome works just fine. The same error occurs on multiple computers and for multiple users.

The server is configured for windows authentication only, with providers NTLM and Negotiate, in that order (and changing the order or removing negotiation or adding kerberos does not help). Extended protection is off and kernel-mode authentication is on (changeing these doesn't help either). I've also tried toggling compatibility mode in the browser, turning enable windows authentication on/off, changing the settings in IE for sending credentials, and moving the site in/out of trusted sites and intranet zone.

No timeout is configured to values this low as far as i can see. The session timeout is 720 minutes, the app pool is set to recycle every 1740 minutes, has idle time-out set to 0 (never), and i've even turned the connection timeout way up. The app pool identity is NetworkService, but I need that.

Any help would be appreciated.